# why redis use "sizeof" to calculate start address of sdshdr

Tags: c, redis

when reading source code of sds in redis,

```
typedef char *sds;

struct sdshdr {
    unsigned int len;
    unsigned int free;
    char buf[];
};

static inline size_t sdslen(const sds s) {
    struct sdshdr *sh = (void*)(s-(sizeof(struct sdshdr)));
    return sh->len;
}
```

I found that ,in function sdslen(),

`struct sdshdr *sh = (void*)(s-(sizeof(struct sdshdr)));`

why not using "offsetof" instead of "sizeof", like this

`struct sdshdr *sh = (void*)(s-(offsetof(struct sdshdr,buf)));`

"sizeof" is working properly here. But when the struct changes a little bit, it will be wrong code.

```
struct sdshdr {
    unsigned int free;
    unsigned int len;
    char c;
    char buf[];
};

int main() {
    unsigned int i = offsetof(struct sdshdr, buf);
    unsigned int s = sizeof(struct sdshdr);
    printf("offset: %u, size: %u\n", i, s);

    struct sdshdr *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct sdshdr) + 100);
    printf("sdshdr address: %p\n", ptr);
    printf("buf address:    %p\n", ptr->buf);
    printf("calculate using sizeof:     %p\n", ptr->buf - sizeof(struct sdshdr));
    printf("calculate using offsetof:   %p\n", ptr->buf - offsetof(struct sdshdr, buf));
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I add a member in struct sdshdr, char c. output of this code is:

`offset: 9, size: 12
sdshdr address: 0x20ce010
buf address:    0x20ce019
calculate using sizeof:     0x20ce00d
calculate using offsetof:   0x20ce010`

now `struct sdshdr *sh = (void*)(s-(sizeof(struct sdshdr)));` is wrong and `struct sdshdr *sh = (void*)(s-(offsetof(struct sdshdr,buf)));` is right.

Comment: What is the question? Why someone used `sizeof` when he could also have used `offsetof`? Maybe he assumed `struct sdshdr` will not be changed or if anyone changes it he will put a `packed` attribute to it so that both methods will be correct.

Comment: @s7amuser actually packed breaks the code: if buf is aligned to 12 then it'll be OK

Comment: @user3528438 How `packed` breaks the code? With `packed` the structure size will be 9 bytes which will be equal to the offset of the `buf` field (assuming `char` is represented as one byte).

Comment: I agree the offsetof approach is better, but I don't think its a good idea to make buf unaligned because it may cause a lot of failures elsewhere.

Comment: @s7amuser `packed` only affect members so the sizeof is still 12

Comment: @user3528438 You are wrong. The `packed` attribute (in `gcc` at least) will remove any padding so the size will be 9. Also, usually headers are declared as `packed` since they are used in buffers and sent over a network or used across different machines. In any case, the `buf` field has byte alignment and that will not change if using `packed`.

Comment: @LPs: `offsetof` is standard as well. `stddef.h` is required for both implementations and relying on `sizeof` yielding the correct value is a bad idea and may result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @s7amuser: Code relying on a `struct` having the same layout as network data is bad design anyway, worse if done like the code above with standard types. The correct way is to properly marshall the fields.

Comment: @Olaf I am not sure I fully understand what you mean but [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ieee80211.h#L228) is a typical example from the Linux kernel of defining a header structure.

Comment: @Olaf My fault about the standard, I wrongly remember that was ANSI C. I'm not used to use it. BTW `stddef.h` is mandatory for `offsetof` only: am I wrong?

Comment: @LPs: It is defined in `stddef.h`, yes. Like `sze_t` which is returned by `sizeof`. But as `stddef.h` is mandatory, there is no problem using any of them. But `sizeof` is definitively wrong to calculate offsets, as it does account for padding after the `struct`.